# Cannot start mongodb after editing .conf file to add new Ip to bindIp

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed mongodb 2.6 in a ubuntu 14.02 server. To allow remote access I added the static Ip to `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
bindIp= 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.150
```

I edited the file as root user using sudo command.

After this mongodb is not starting as service on boot up. But I can start it using following command :

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

As I understand I made some permission problem while editing conf file. I tried a few solutions including changing owner of /etc folder to mongodb as well as current system user. But they are not working. I am a very new user to linux environment. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Result of `ls -l /etc/mongod.conf`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1716 Aug 14 23:32 /etc/mongod.conf
```

Also the result for the command:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

is:

```
mongod start/running, process 2660.
```

But if I try to open mongo client with mongo, I get

```
errno:111 connection refused, connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
```

Comment: By changing the owner of `/etc` you may have broken any number of things, or at least substantially impacted the security of your system.  You should never modify permissions on `/etc`.

Comment: I have formatted that system and again installed mongodb and edited bindip in conf file. The same problem repeated. But this time I have not changed any permission. I wanted to hear suggestions before proceeding.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the output of `ls -l /etc/mongod.conf`?  Is mongo logging any errors in the application log?  Or is there anything in the system log that looks relevant?

Answer (score 2):

this line should be: 
bindIp=[127.0.0.1,192.168.0.150]

Comment: This is the correct solution. I experienced this error after following the DigitalOcean tutorial for installing Mongo on Ubuntu18.04 and they left out the brackets. Thanks Danny!